# Visual Studio 2017 .NET Core Application: Publish to folder and delete existing files

Tags: visual-studio-2017

How do you publish a .NET Core console application to a folder and choose to "Remove existing files" in the destination folder? There does not seem to be any option in the GUI. Is there perhaps a setting in the pubxml file?

This is what my GUI looks like:
[image]

Comment: Ah its my mistake, I missed the fact that it was a console app.  I've just tried publishing a net.core console app and got the same GUI as you have.

Comment: I've just tried adding <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles> to the pubxml and visual studio totally ignored it.

Comment: I know this is late and obviously you found the solution but incase someone else comes to this thread in the future, it is fond in the "Settings..." menu.

Comment: The verdict so far for this question was that Visual Studio, at the time of writing, supports deleting existing files for web applications, but not for console applications.